# MATLAB: Generate same Random Number sequence

Tags: matlab, random

I want to use the mersenne twister to generate 'N' random numbers between 10 to 50. I want to be able to generate the same sequence over and over again.

I wrote the following code: (seed = 50, a = 10, b = 50, N = number of required random numbers)

```
s = rng(seed, 'twister');
r = a + (b-a)*rand(N,1);
rng(s);
r1 = a + (b-a)*rand(N,1);
```

Now even I print

```
r1 - r
```

I don't get zero. I expect to get zero as I have reset the random number generator to it's initial state in the third line of my code.

My question is where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you get something very close to zero, it is just floating point error

Comment: No I'm getting significant errors of the order of 10.

Comment: And if the random numbers produced are the same in r1 and r, I shouldn't even be getting floating point errors as they should be **exactly** the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`rng` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html):

> `sprev = rng(...)` returns the previous settings of the random number generator used by `rand`, `randi`, and `randn` before changing the settings.

So your `s` is the previous state, not the set state.  Changing things to

```
rng(seed, 'twister');
s=rng();
r = a + (b-a)*rand(N,1);
rng(s);
r1 = a + (b-a)*rand(N,1);
```

should produce the desired behavior.

This may seem cumbersome, but it arises since `rng` is meant to be treated like a toggle: you set your state while storing the previous one for future restoration.  After all, immediately resetting the state appears to be more diagnostic than practical.